# How to modify the appendix chapter numbering?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I have:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Title}
\section{Intro}
```

and it appears.

> Appendix A
>   Title
>   A.1 Intro

I would like to have the same except the "A.1 Intro" but instead "1.Intro"

How to remove the "A."?

Answer (score 9):

Just change the representation for section numbers:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\chapter{Title}
\section{Intro}\label{appsec:intro}
```

Remember, though, that references such as `\ref{appsec:intro}` will appear just as "1", without any clue for the appendix "number".

Answer (score 2):

Place `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` after `\appendix` to change the section numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to modify that line so that no section letters appear, as in the case when there is only one appendix?

Comment: @Forest: Did you tried `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}`?

Comment: @MartinScharrer In the end, I re-formatted the appendix so that it made sense to have section letters. I hadn't figured out how to remove them by the time the document was due. :) Next time...