# Remove dot after appendix numbering

Tags: numbering, koma-script, punctuation, appendices

I want my appendix section numbering to look like this

```
Appendix
A Section one
B Section two
```

I've figured out how to get the A and B (see question [How to modify the appendix chapter numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21798/5065)). But with the solution described there I get the following:

```
Appendix
A. Section one
B. Section two
```

How can I remove the dot after the A and B?

Here is my latex file

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,version=first,listof=totoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12,index=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=altlist,order=word,hyperfirst=true]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{glossar}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=alphabetic,citestyle=diplomarbeit,language=ngerman]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
   \tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\backmatter
   \appendix
   \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
   \chapter{Appendix}
   \section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is not your first question, so you should know that you should provide _at least_ the documentclass which you are using.

Comment: Added some latex lines ^^

Comment: and it maybe obvious that packages like `rotating`, `multirow` aso have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: It is obvious ^^

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can switch off the dot using the optional argument `numbers=noenddot` for the `scrbook` documentclass.

*Minimal* working example:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
   \tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\backmatter
   \appendix
   \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
   \chapter{Appendix}
   \section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I've searched for "latex scrbook options" but found no adequate site where to find such information... how can I find them?

Comment: @strauberry: `texdoc scrbook` brings up the KOMA-script documentation, also available [on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf).

Comment: Is it possible to _only_ remove the enddots für the appendix sections? This solution also removes the enddot for normal chapters.

Comment: Use \renewcommand{\autodot}{} to remove enddots thereafter