# Stop section numbers from starting with . (making `.1 Example title` to `1 Example title`)

Tags: sectioning, overleaf

Am compiling a document using latex in overleaf where the appendix is being generated with `.` at the front of the section and subsection numbers as shown in the image below.

How would one stop this from occurring? Making `.1 Example` to `1 Example`.

I have added a minimum working example with all the packages that I have to help illustrate the problem and a solution.

[image: ![enter image description here]

***minimum working example***

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,afrikaans,english,masters-t,goldenblock]{usthesis}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[afrikaans, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg} % To be able to add SVG images
\usepackage{usbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\setcitestyle{square}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sets page size and margins %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,  total={210.2mm,297.3mm}, left=25mm, right = 25mm, top=26.3mm, bottom=43.8mm }

\begin{document}

Body.

\appendix

\section{Example 1} % error comes here (remove dot)

\subsection{Example 2} % and error also comes here (remove dot)

\bibliography{sample} % no need for bibliography

\end{document}
```

- Adding `numbers=noenddot` to the `documentclass` did not work.
- Adding chapter before appendix, as suggested below by @AmirParvardi I am getting something like this:

1. in main

[image]

2. in file holding the appendix scripts

[image]

3. output generated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing a MWE! This is happening because, as far as I know, appendices come in chapters, so if you just add a `\chapter{}` before the first `\section{}` in the appendix, you will like what you see.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,afrikaans,english,masters-t,goldenblock]{usthesis}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[afrikaans, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg} % To be able to add SVG images
\usepackage{usbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\setcitestyle{square}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sets page size and margins %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,  total={210.2mm,297.3mm}, left=25mm, right = 25mm, top=26.3mm, bottom=43.8mm }

\begin{document}
Body.
\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix Title}
\section{Section Example}
\subsection{Subsection Example}
\bibliography{sample} % no need for bibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Appendix]

Comment: Hi @AmirParvardi , I am getting something a bit different with this method.

Comment: Instead, I am getting the chapter with no number but the . does not disappear.

Comment: Yes, the chapter does not have a number because it is basically the title of Appendix A. For removing the dot, refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25729/remove-dot-after-appendix-numbering) topic.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the initial dot, insert after `\appendix` and before `\section`

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

[image: a]

With

```
\begin{document}
    
    Body.
    
    \backmatter     
    \appendix
    \chapter{Back matter chapter}
    
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \section{Section Example 1} % initial dot removed 
    
    \subsection{Subsection Example 2} %  initial dot removed 
    
%   \bibliography{sample} % no need for bibliography
    
\end{document}
```

this is the output:

[image: b]

Comment: Thanks @SimonDispa