# Eliminate the last point in the numbering of the headings using scrreprt

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrreprt

I am using scrreprt and would like to have no dot after the last digit of the numbering of the headings (2.3. -> 2.3). The same with all other things like figures, tables and listings. I have managed to get it to do that in the text, but in the table of contents the dots remain.

please help me to save my bachelor thesis :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us some compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Are you looking for the option `numbers=noenddot`?

Comment: In the text I managed to get the points out with the following code:

Comment: \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mylabel}{#1 #2}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mylabel}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=mylabel}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelformat=mylabel}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname \ }
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter \ } 

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt
]{tocline}{chapter}
But in the table of contents, that I insert with \tableofcontens, points are displayed anyway.

Comment: If the code from your comment is relevant for the question, please add it to the question. BTW: Showing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) is always recommended. And have you tried the option proposed by Keks Dose? If it does not help, you really should show a minimal working example, because it is the recommended option to not automatically add a final dot to numbers with KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: ok, sorry, I am new here and didn't knew that. Where can I put the option from Keks Dose, in which part of the code?

Comment: @SimonHüsges Put it into the general options, I'll give as example: `\documentclass[english, DIV=classic, BCOR=5mm, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}`. And the command `texdoc packagename`, e.g. `texdoc scrguien` (ok, bad example) is your friend. Type this on the command line and you will get the manual. `texdoc babel` will provide the manual of the babel package.

Comment: @KeksDose `texdoc scrguien` was indeed correct for several decades. But the manuals have been renamed. Therefore `texdoc scrguide-en` for the English user manual and `texdoc scrguide-de` for the German user manual would be correct now. BTW: `texdoc scrreprt` would also work.

Comment: @SimonHüsges Please read (one of) the section(s) about setting options in of the KOMA-Script manuals, e.g., section 3.1. Reading a LaTeX introduction could also help, because setting of class options should be explained there too.

Comment: Also related: [Remove dot after appendix numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25729/277964).